# set yticks colors to match barplot colors python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to figure out how to set y names to match the color of the barplot that corresponds to it. So every publisher name has the same color as the bar next to it, like PS2 will be pink, 3DS green and so on.

```
f, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
sns.barplot(x=gbyplat,y=gbyplat.index, palette='husl')
plt.ylabel('Publisher', color='deepskyblue', size=15, alpha=0.8)
plt.xlabel('Number of titles published', color='slateblue', size=15, alpha=0.7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the ticklabels and set the respective color from the palette.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

l =list("ABCDEFGHIJK")
x = np.arange(1,len(l)+1)[::-1]
f, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
sns.barplot(x=x,y=l, palette='husl', ax=ax)
plt.ylabel('Publisher', color='deepskyblue', size=15, alpha=0.8)
plt.xlabel('Number of titles published', color='slateblue', size=15, alpha=0.7)

p = sns.color_palette("husl", len(l))
for i, label in enumerate(ax.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_color(p[i])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Now after I did this I came up with another idea, where maybe I would split the 'Publisher' ylabel into three parts and every of those parts would get the same color as the nearest barplot. So right now I'm using the code from: http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/rainbow_text.html    However Im not sure what i should pass under ax argument in the function so that it will appear as ylabel for this plot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh and another thing I'm rewriting the code in 'MATLAB style interfrace' so there are no ax and fig, and do you know how can I change the `ax.get_yticklabels()` without using object ax to get same result? `plt.yticks` doesnt work.

Comment: For the ylabel you can leave the `ax=None` but you will need to find the correct coordinates to put the text to. Concerning the ticklabels, what would be the reason not to use the code from the answer using an axes handle `ax`?

Comment: Yes I was doing it manually by fidning coords, but is there a way to get ylabel coords? For the second thing i'm doing it just to understand differences between object oriented programming in matplotlib and the classic approach. I understand the code from the answer and i used it but now i want to rewrite it without creating objects, however for that part of code i'm stuck.

Comment: The objects are created anyways, whether you use them or not. Python is an object oriented language and matplotlib is making use of it throughout its code. It just provides `pyplot` as an interface which makes it easy to use, especially for people coming from Matlab. Internally most pyplot commands are simply rerouted to the underlying objects (e.g. `plt.xticks()` simply calls `ax.get_xticks()` and `ax.get_xticklabels()` internally). So since there is no pyplot interface for getting the individual ticklabels, you need to use the methods from the axes class.

Comment: Obtaining the ylabel coordinates is not of much use, when using the matplolib rainbow text example, since the label is centered at 0.5 axes-height, but you need to start your label at a lower coordinate anyways.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. So there is actually no way doing certain visualizations using just pyplot interface so it's better to use axes straight out right?

Comment: And in this code is there an argument passable for the ax in rainbowtext or is the coordinates method the only one?

Comment: We're talking about two very different questions here (which are also unrelated to the original question). You may reformulate them into consise new questions if you feel the need.